Rough major events in the evolution of speech organs (even before language)?
I am listening to the audiobook "The Language Puzzle" and it is starting to get into how Chimpanzees and other apes/monkeys can make a small set of sounds (hoots, grunts, etc.), but they can't really form sound sequences and don't have the same long vocal tract that humans do, and the muscle control of mouth/voice muscles, which is required for modern human speech.

2 million years ago we were chipping rocks making stone tools.
Thereabout control of fire emerged.
Some fossils of vocal bones suggest Heidelbergensis might have developed longer vocal tracts capable of human speech, and other related sparse facts which I'm not fully aware of. 500kya.
~200-300kya homo sapiens emerge
60kya another out of africa dispersal
Then by 50kya we were drawing cave paintings.
Land bridge Native Americans crossed roughly 15-25kya.
10kya, we were starting to write scripts on permanent material.
Ancient texts recorded, and spiritual traditions passed down orally, with rich belief systems.

So for at least 500,000 years, we were chipping rocks and controlling fires. And somehow our speech organs had to evolve until they were capable of speaking all the vowels and consonants and chaining them together into words. And control the breath and diaphram, etc..
I imagine by 100kya, we were singing around the campfire, rock chipping going on in the background, and singing beautiful melodies to the group/family. It is only logical that this would have had to emerge to lead to the beautiful music and mythologies we have today.
What is a rough timeline of important events, or hypotheses of timelines, that led to the ability to say all of our vowels and consonants, and possibly control the breath to chain them into individual words. Potentially way before a language or grammar was even needed.
Inspired to ask this question after listening to this melody, which almost depicts an ancient scene where ancient stone-age hunter-gatherers could have been humming around the fire, with the tick of the beat the rock chipping going on in the background.
I am not wondering about how to do complicated stuff like when speaking modern languages emerged. But like this song (just the parts that aren't saying words), we just had humming along to a beat.
It appears to me at first brainstorming that the steps could have been:

hoots and calls of chimps
chipping rocks for thousands of years, forming a regular beat in the background, representing peace and safety and security and longevity, for they could use the resulting tools for food and other things.
humming to the beat (mmm sound at first perhaps, because maybe vowels could have evolved after humming and controlling the breath).
vowels shortly after, basic "ee" "ah" and "oo".
And perhaps a few key consonants like the "k" or "t" representing the chipping rock tick sound, and "sh" the flow of a river, and "s" the sleeping breath, and "h" or "f" the wind, etc..
And at the same time, experimenting with matching sounds to the environment tones, for pitch and melody development.

So you might have:
iiiiii
aaaaaa
uuuuuu

That would be a fairly complex sequence of sounds, especially if combined with musical tones like the linked melody.
So at first it's like, controlling breath, and humming, then perhaps simple melody developments and rhythms. After a while they start chaining together vowels/consonants in their melodies to form sound bundles, or words, which convey a complex idea. Then much later they realize they can speak these words faster and more accurately, to evolve into modern language.
So my question is, how do we get to the first steps of being able to say all the consonants and vowels of modern English/Spanish? (More specifically, these 27 sounds). I don't need an answer for each sound, but more like, what are the things that would have had to evolve to support making these sounds, and singing them to pitches? And roughly where can I find the evidence in what bone structures or muscles, to support the timeline?

See also this answer: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/26654/9781

This seems like a reasonable question to me, though I don't know enough about paleontology or physiology to answer it. Do note, though, that some linguists theorize that signed languages developed before spoken ones—dextrous hands are more useful for other purposes than the elaborate vocal tract, which wouldn't be useful until we'd evolved our various communication abilities.

Although the question is reasonable, a reasonable answer is more like a book than a stackexchange answer. And ask ten palaeoanthropologists and get a dozen answers, there is little firm ground there.
